# Compare different rows of a mdx query between them

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

I need some help. I'm trying to compare different rows of a mdx query between them.
For example, imagine I have 2 different columns (Col1 and Col2 which are entities and they mean something like Col1 has to pay Col2) and I have 1 measure (the amount that Col1 have to pay for Col2). My query gets a result like the following.

```
Col1 | Col2 | Result
A    |  B   |  20
A    |  C   |  30 
B    |  C   |  10
B    |  A   |  -20
C    |  A   |  -30
C    |  B   |  -10
```

I'm not able to check for example if the amount from A to B and the amount from B to A are the same.
Can someone give me an advice ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a SSRS expression to determine the Result value to be paid by Col2 to Col1.

Create a new column in your tablix using this expression:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Col2.Value & Fields!Col1.Value,
Fields!Col1.Value & Fields!Col2.Value,Fields!Result.Value,"DataSetName")
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of yours.

It will give you the corresponding Result value:

[image]

If there is no a row for a specific Col2 - Col1 relation it will produce `Nothing` value.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I didn't thought about this solution. Thank you so much ! perfect !